# WordPress - Backward Compatiblity

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, backwards-compatibility

So I am learning WordPress Theme Development and came across something on WordPress.org about backward compatibility. I went to look at the functions that go into creating partial templates like: [wp_body_open()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_body_open/). On this page, they have a comment that talks about backward compatibility. They have a function like this:

```
<?php 
    if ( function_exists( 'wp_body_open' ) ) {
        wp_body_open();
    } else {
        do_action( 'wp_body_open' );
    }
?>
```

I kind of understand what it does but, I want to know how and why this is considered backward compatible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `wp_body_open()` has been introduced in WP 5.2.0. If you try to run the code that will call `wp_body_open()` on earlier WP it will cause fatal error.

The code you've mentioned first checks the existence of the function. If it exists than it is called. If it doesn't exist only the hook is used. That way it won't cause error even when the code is used with older WP. That's what backward compatibility means.

Comment: Ok this makes since thanks. I just didn't know how and why it was backwards compatible.